# Is there a way of determining if ajax errors in a js file are logged on a server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, logging

Is there a way to tell if ajax error are being logged somewhere, by simply looking at the code?

We have a copy of a page, and it's throwing errors because we're not logged in. . ..  but we don't really care about logging in, as we're really just testing and moving around code etc. But we're not the original owners of the code, so we literally copied off elements and are just playing with functionalities on a local server. We just don't want the poor programmer to be getting a ton of errors and going spazz when we're just moving and playing with the code on our end.

The code that we're concerned about is:

```
//----------------------------- Called each time the page is loaded -------//
function init(){
//launch session time out counter
startSession();
//store Q answers
//$('#questionnaire').data('firstChange', true);
$('#questionnaire').data('q1', $('[name="A"]:checked').val());
$('#questionnaire').data('q2', $('[name="B"]:checked').val());
$('#questionnaire').data('q3', $('[name="C"]:checked').val());
$('#questionnaire').data('q4', $('[name="D"]:checked').val());
//reset flags
$('#content').data('clickBound', true);
$('#content').data('payerJson', null);
$('#content').data('myValidator', null);

//Handle different types of Ajax errors
$.ajaxSetup({
error:function(x,e){
    if(x.status==0 || x.status==401){
        var answer = confirm("You're logged out the application. Click on \"Ok\" to log in again.");
        if(answer){
            window.location="./";
        }
    }else if(x.status==404){
    alert('Requested URL not found. Please check your network connection and try to log in again.');
    }else if(x.status==500){
    alert('Internal Server Error. Please try to log out and log in again.');
    }else if(e=='parsererror'){
    alert("Error.\nParsing Request failed. Please try to log out and log in again.");
    }else if(e=='timeout'){
    alert('Request Time out. Please check your network connection and try to log in again.');
    }else {
    alert("Unknown Error.\n"+x.responseText + "\n Please try to log out and log in again on.");
    }
},
cache : false
});
```

Comment: You didn't close your function `}`.

Comment: You are asking if its possible to determine what the server is doing from client side code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is as already answered: there is no way to tell from javascript what the server will do with the data it gets.

You can determine however if a code sends data anywhere else but your own server. The snippet you provided does not start any ajax calls, so unless there are other parts which send information directly to the original owner's server, I would say you are safe from giving him/her headache.

For being sure, check the urls of the ajax calls, and/or use the network tab in developer tools to see if there is any non-intended communication going on.

Answer (score 1):

There is not way to determine what is happening on the server based on looking at the client side code.  That is unless the client side code passed some sort of data to the server to tell it to log in a particular way.  Even then, you would have no way of knowing if the server was truly logging the request, without going on to the server and looking.

Bottom line here is that the server is going to determine the server's logging behavior, not the client.